# Pairing to Mac Connection Failed

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I use VS 2022 17.6 and also VS 2022 17.8 Preview to connect to my to develop under .NET MAUI.

My problem is that very often I can't establish a connection to Pair with my Mac

[image]

What I do then is clear Data on my Mac restart my Mac and also Windows and try again. I also try and delete my .vs-Directory. Sometimes it helps, sometimes it doesn't.

When this is displayed, it is hardly possible to re-connect again. Sometimes I also loose the Connection to my Mac when it first worked well for long time. But, after losing it, it is not possible anymore to re-connect unless I try above steps.

Is there anything that I should setup or do, maybe also on the Mac that helps with these connection issues? Problem is, it takes so long to get it up and running again that it is a real pain in the ass and very time-consuming.

Comment: Have you enabled the option: `Enable auto connection to known Macs` under Tools\Options\Xamarin\iOS settings in VS?

Comment: Are your Mac on wireless network? Also try to disable eveything that is sleep mode. Another thing, if you have several VS open you sometimes need to close all of them, to make a reconnection in my experiences.

Comment: Yes this option is active. My Mac is connected to the Wireless Network. What can I disable regarding Sleep Mode. Is there anything you know of? I have just one of my VS open at the same time

Comment: Try to put your mac on a fixed connection. Also go to System Settings and search sleep and Energy Saving. `Wake for network access` should be on. And `Prevent automatic sleeping when display is off` should be on. Turn off `Put hard disk to sleep when possible`. This is how I make this work more consistently. I need to close down VS once in a while but never restart the MAC or my PC. I hope this helps.

Comment: These, I already had. I could also try to add a WLAN Hotspot (Mobile Hotspot) on my PC and connect to this on my Mac, if this makes sense?

Comment: @OXO This is sensible, you can do it.

Comment: I will let you guys know after a couple of days if it got more stable by doing this. Already thank you very much for your valuable hints

Comment: Feedback so far: My impression is that it is way more stable like this. Reconnects work much much better and I get less errors starting the IDB. BUT, it still happens that the communication gets destroyed and I just see "Simulator" instead of "iPhone 14 iOS 16.2" in the VS Toolbar. Still strange why this happens. At least, re-connect seems to work better. Previously it was most of the time only possible to connect by restarting both systems, deleting Caches on Mac, deleting .vs-Directory and so on...

Comment: Another problem came up so that very often when I click the Stop-Button in Debugger to stop the execution on iPad-Simulator it crashes so crazy that sometimes I have to reboot both systems to get the connection for this simulator up and running again (VS 2022 17.8 - Preview)

Comment: @OXO Does this issue only exist on VS 2022 17.8 - Preview? And it works fine on VS 2022 17.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the connection more stable when pairing to Mac, you can refer to the suggestions below:

1. Automatic connection to known Macs can be enabled in Visual Studio by navigating to **Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS** Settings and ensuring that **Enable auto connection to known Macs** is checked:
2. In **System Settings > Energy Saver**, check the `Wake for network access` option and uncheck `Put hard disks to sleep when possible`. Also make sure check `Prevent automatic sleeping when display is off`. Thanks to Peter's effort.
3. You can also add a WLAN Hotspot (Mobile Hotspot) on your PC and connect to this on the Mac.
4. If you click the Stop-Button in Debugger to stop the execution on iPad-Simulator and you have to reboot both systems to get the connection for waking up the simulator particularly on VS 2022 17.8 - Preview, you can report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem", see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)

Comment: This is still my biggest pain during Development. Everyday it is the same. Can't connect, waiting on the Simulator which does not want to be opened up etc.
I even switched from connecting via Wi-Fi-Connection to connecting PC and Mac via Ethernet, which seemed to help in some cases but then the next day also same issues connecting. It's a pain in the ass I have to say.

Comment: Yes, it's really annoying if you need to fix the connection issue everyday before developing the App. Since it's VS tool issue, I think you can [report a problem with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201) as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the better part of an afternoon on this.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.10.0 Preview 2.0 on Windows.  According to the post below, these issues should have been resolved.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-Pair-to-Mac-since-upgrading-bo/10439082

I got the the point where no combination of rebooting either Windows VM or the entire MAC would work.

I was going to grab the logs from the post mentioned above and open a new case (since everything is locked down/closed), and discovered something by accident.

If I close Visual Studio and delete all the log files from both locations, I can pair to the MAC again. Every time this error pops up I have followed that process and can connect once again.  It's a relief...

Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs\17.0\
MAC: ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin.Messaging-

Hope this may help someone else.

Comment: I will try next time I have such issues. I also use VS 17.10.0 Preview 1 and Preview 2 and must say, it got way better. It also helped to just hibernate my MAC. When I have to restart, it helped to start Windows first and then MAC second. That’s probably because I use Connection Sharing from Windows to MAC. And with these VS version I click on Forget this Mac and add it back in after a restart of VS